# Do $p_\mu$ and $\gamma^\mu$ commute?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

So I am trying to derive the relation $\bar{u}_{(s)} (\displaystyle{\not}{p} -m)=0$ from the conjugate dirac equation $(i \partial_\mu\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu+m\bar\psi) = 0$ but I am running into issue. Given that $\bar{\psi}=\bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}$, we can plug in and see $$\begin{align}i\partial_\mu\bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx} \gamma^\mu + m \bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx} &= i(ip_\mu)\bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}\gamma^\mu+ m \bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}\\&=-p_\mu \bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}\gamma^\mu+m \bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}\ = 0\end{align}$$
then  $$\begin{align} -\bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}p_\mu \gamma^\mu+m \bar{u}_{s} e^{ipx}\ = 0 \rightarrow \bar{u}_{s} (p_\mu \gamma^\mu-m  )=0\ \\ \end{align}$$

but I thought $\gamma^\mu p_\mu \not=p_\mu\gamma^\mu$, where is my logic flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I thought $\gamma^\mu p_\mu \not=p_\mu\gamma^\mu$, where is my logic flawed?

Your logic is flawed right at the beginning--right from your premise: "I thought $\gamma^\mu p_\mu \not=p_\mu\gamma^\mu$."

What you denote by $\gamma^\mu$ is a 4-by-4 matrix of numbers.

What you denote by $p_\mu$ is a number.

A number commutes with a matrix of numbers.

The fact that you are summing over $\mu$ changes nothing, since each term in the sum is a number times a matrix of numbers.

So:
$$
\gamma^\mu p_\mu = p_\mu \gamma^\mu
$$

---

> do $p_\mu$ and $\gamma^\mu$ commute?

Yes, they do commute.